# Unable to login to snowflake account trial version - "IP [] is not allowed to access Snowflake. Contact your local security administrator."

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, static-ip-address

I am unable to connect back to snowflake and given that this is a trial version, I do not know how to add my IP address into the network policy. [Please see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM98h.png). I have loaded all the required data using this POC version and not sure how to log-back. I had selected azure as cloud partner while setting this account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contact with Snowflake support and ask them to disable network policy.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html

Go to snowflake community:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/

Register and login, and then click "submit a case". Select "I am a 30-day trial user", and validate yourself. Then you should be able to submit a case.